# Can I connect a camera to an arduino mini?

Tags: sd-card, arduino-micro

I was wondering if it was possible to connect a camera like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HD-Mini-CCTV-Camera-Security-Micro-Audio-Wired-600TVL-1-4-5Mp-0-5LUX-/171421181800?hash=item27e97fa768:g:MbMAAOSwEK9T7Fwt) onto an Arduino mini and have the Arduino save video and audio to a micro SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Not really (at least, not with any appreciable quality). Basically, the bandwidth involved is simply too much for the Arduino's relatively slow 16MHz core speed. You might be able to periodically capture greyscale lowres frames, but capturing the full 1280x960 resolution at any decent framerate is basically impossible.

If you want to find Arduino projects that involve capturing video like this, the search term is `arduino composite video input`. There are many projects out there that interface the Arduino with a composite input, but none that I know of that can capture full video. Consider the following: your Arduino runs at 16 MHz. If you were to handle 640x480 greyscale video (1 byte per pixel), that would be a data bandwidth (disregarding signal bandwidth) of 640*480*30 = 9216000 bytes/second. That's a pretty tall order: even if you could process each pixel in two (single cycle) instructions with no overhead, you still wouldn't have enough processor bandwidth.

If all you want to do is record composite video to an SD card, there are far easier options out there, search `composite video recorder sd`.